# Where does the php exit function print its message to?

Tags: php

According to http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_misc_exit.asp the php exit function prints a message and exits the current script. Where does the message get printed?

Comment: Don't use w3schools as a php resource, use the official docs: http://php.net/exit  The PHP docs explain it better (the parameter is *optional*, not *required*).

Comment: The same place that the `print` function prints.

Comment: Try it and see what happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `exit()` function outputs to standard out. Typically this is sent right back to the client (Browser), but a lot of things might interfere with that: Bad Output buffering or redirection e.g.

Answer (score 1):

If you pass it a string, it gets echoed to the screen (just like if you were to use `echo`).

If you pass it an int, it's not displayed, but instead "returned" as the program's [return code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status).

Answer (score 0):

It outputs it to the browser, you see a plain page with the exit message, or if previous output was printed then it appends this to the bottom.